# psr4 changes after upgrade have class not found symfony 2,4 -> 2,8

Tags: symfony, psr-4, symfony-2.8

I use  "symfony/symfony": "~2.4", 
and configuration

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/", "Mea":"vendor/", "mea":"vendor/Mea/CoreBundle/", "Place":"vendor/Mea/"  }
    },
```

i create new project with "symfony/symfony": "2.8.x-dev",

first i get error

```
[InvalidArgumentException]                                     
  a non-empty PSR-4 prefix must end with a namespace separator.
```

so i add

```
 "autoload": {
            "psr-4": { "": "src/","Mea\\":"vendor/", "mea\\":"vendor/Mea/CoreBundle/", "SymfonyStandard\\": "app/SymfonyStandard/" }
        },
```

and have ClassNotFoundException

when i try access to classes in this folder

example :

```
 $a = \mea\pattern\view::inst();
```

give my

```
Attempted to load class "view" from namespace "mea\pattern".
Did you forget a "use" statement for "mea\pattern\view"?
500 Internal Server Error - ClassNotFoundException
```

how to fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The namespace you configured is "Mae" (camel cased), but in the code you use "mae" (lower cased). [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) is case sensitive:

> All class names MUST be referenced in a case-sensitive fashion.